# Importing Images onto Tkinter Canvas Failed

Tags: python-3.x, image, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So I'm trying to make a simple login page for a bigger project, and I'm adding images and running it constantly, but every time I run it, it gives me this "error: _tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=70x70 at 0x1AEE532D780>" doesn't exist". I'm really new to tkinter, but I've been with python for almost 4 months now.Could anyone please help me with this?

I tried to add an image as a background and one as a logo. I was expecting it to load in and make the plain Login look good. I'm really new to tkinter and am facing a lot of trouble, and I'm struggling a lot because in most tutorials, they write code, and I write the same but our outcomes are different.If there are any errors in the question please comment and explain because this is my first question on Stack Overflow and I'm still trying to understand the functions. Thank you!

Here is my updated code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import messagebox

def login(name,pwd):
    if len(name)==0:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Authentication", message="Enter Username")
    elif len(pwd)==0:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Authentication", message="Enter Password")
    elif name=='admin':
        if pwd=='p4$$w0Rd':
            messagebox.showinfo(title="Authentication", message="Woohoo! Sucessfully authenticated and logged in :D !")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Authentication", message="Oh no! Failed to Authenicate and Login D: !")
else:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Authentication", message="Oh no! Failed to Authenicate and Login D: !")





root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
root.title("Krypton OS Login Page")

bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Apps\Login\wallpaper.jpg"))
label=tk.Label(image=bg)
label.place(x=0,y=0)


img = Image.open("Apps\Login\Login.jpg")
#img = img.resize((70, 70))
rgb_img = img.convert("RGB")
rgb_img.save("Login.jpg")
label1 = tk.Label(image=img)
label1.place(x=150, y=30)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text = "User Name", font=(10))
label2.place(x=50, y=120)

name_var = tk.StringVar()
uname = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=name_var, width=15,font=(10))
uname.place(x=160,y=120)

label3 = tk.Label(root, text="Password", font=(10))
label3.place(x=50, y=160)

pwd_var = tk.StringVar()
pwd = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=pwd_var, width=15,font=(10), 
show="*")
pwd.place(x=160,y=160)

B = tk.Button(root,text="LOGIN", 
width=15,fg="red",bg="black",command=lambda:login(name_var.get(), 
pwd_var.get()))
B.place(x=160,y=210)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: `<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=512x512 at 0x1FF26A5D840>` is not an error. Please provide the error traceback. Also I really doubt that there are fake tutorials. Are you sure you aren't misunderstanding those tutorials?

Comment: The code you added should have a background (`"wallpaper.jpg"`) but it's possible that the image is too small or all of the other widgets are covering the background. Also you have problems with not converting `img` into a `PhotoImage` before using `tk.Label(image=img)`.

Comment: Mmmmmm... I tried a piece of code but the error is back. I don't think I understand the solution about converting img to PhotoImage

Comment: You need to add `img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rgb_img)` before `label1 = tk.Label(image=img)`.

Answer (score 0):

So first, you need to fix the resizing process of your background and the visualisation of ur label by doing that :

```
bg = (Image.open(r"YourPath"))
bg2 = bg.resize((400,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bg2)
label=tk.Label(image=bg)
label.pack()
```

Then, for the login.jpg there is almost the same problem do this :

```
img = Image.open(r"YourPath")
img2 = img.resize((70, 70))
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
label1 = tk.Label(image=img)
```

Now It should work I already tested it If u need something tell me.
I hope this helped.